# Mule: referencing values from sub array to insert into database

Tags: mule

My incoming Payload is something like this, this is an ArrayList

```
  payload :[[a3An00000009Ej6EAE, a3An00000009EjGEAU, a3An00000009EjBEAU], [45000.0, 50000.0, 12000.0]]
```

I have more than one array in my incoming data.

I can reference the id value as #[message.payload.id]& put it in the insert statement:

```
 <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO HDR_TABLE (ID) VALUES (#[message.payload.id])]]</db:parameterized-query>
```

how can I reference two separate arrays in the code?

```
  <db:bulk-execute config-ref="Oracle_Configuration" doc:name="Database"><![CDATA[
```

INSERT INTO xxtw.XXTW_OE_CONTRACT_LINE(CONTRACT_LINE_ID,ATTRIBUTE1)VALUES(xxtw.XXTW_OE_CONTRACT_LINE_SEQ.NEXTVAL,'#[payload[0][0]]', '#[payload[0][1]]')

```
                                                                                                           ]]></db:bulk-execute>                                                                                                  
     <!--  <foreach doc:name="For Each" collection="#[flowVars.extendedPrice]">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to insert a list of record into a table in database, we can utilize the **Bulk Mode** option inside the **Basic Settings** in Database connector's property. By enabling this option, we do not need to loop through the list/array.

Since **Bulk mode** operations require Iterable/Iterator as input. We have to make sure that the Payload is a List. In this case, if the expected result is all value of the *id* and *lineID* are inserted to the same table, HDR_TABLE. Then, we have to merge them as a List and override the Payload.

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[
    payload.lineID.add(payload.id);
    payload = payload.lineID;]]>
</expression-component>
```

If only need to insert the *lineID* into the HDR_TABLE, then directly set the payload.

```
<set-payload value="#[payload.lineID]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Finally modify the query:

```
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[INSERT INTO HDR_TABLE (ID) VALUES (#[payload])]]</db:parameterized-query>
```

---

IMHO, the edited question is slightly different with the original one. However in order to insert the arrays without looping, we still use the Bulk Mode option (Operation = Insert, Query Type = Parameterized). Then put an additional step to merge the payload together into a single list of consecutive n-tuples.

1. The payload is an array of arrays: `[[a3An00000009Ej6EAE, a3An00000009EjGEAU, a3An00000009EjBEAU], [45000.0, 50000.0, 12000.0]]`. It will be misinterpreted by *Database* connector, even Bulk Mode is activated. *Database* will think that there are only two records. Since the main array consist of two records/arrays.
2. Whereas the expected payload is a list with 3 records. Therefore, we need to merge them become something like a key-value pair record. So it will be like this: `[[a3An00000009Ej6EAE, 45000.0], [a3An00000009EjGEAU, 50000.0], [a3An00000009EjBEAU, 12000.0]]`
3. In order to produce the expected payload, then put an additional transformer, **Set Payload**. Set its value with this expression: `#[dw('payload[0] zip payload[1]')]`
4. Finally, refine the SQL query become: `INSERT INTO tableName (col1, col2) VALUES(#[payload[0]], #[payload[1]])`

Comment: Hello Sulthony, a further amendment to my code . My payload is an array of arrays, & I need to take one from each & insert, In other words I want to insert #payload[0],[0]. How can that be achieved I have updated the code above. Looking forward for your input

Comment: HI Sulthony, appreciate the great response!

Answer (score 0):

You can split the payload.lineID with delimiter as ',' which produces an array.

From that array you can actually get the values by using Index.